# php exec openoffice macro windows 7

Tags: php, windows, shell, command-line, macros

I am having a problem executing commands from php. The code works fine using the command line directly on windows. I am also able to execute a test command using php to create a simple empty text file however when I try to execute my macro nothing happens. I also but the code into a bat file and tried executing the bat file and same thing, nothing happened. I am not getting any errors in the error log or output to the screen. I am using a WAMP install.

I have also tried running wamp as administrator and setting full access permissions on soffice.exe for all users.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Thanks for your time.

```
shell_exec('"C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenOffice.org 3/program/soffice.exe" -invisible -headless -norestore macro:///Standard.doc2html.SaveAsHTML("{MYPATH}/MYDOC.doc")');
```

{MYPATH}/MYDOC is short for the real path, the path is correct as it works just fine from the direct command line.

This is the test code that worked from within php

```
shell_exec('cd. > "{MYPATH}/test.txt"');
```

Comment: You have given us very little to go on beyond just an explanation.

Comment: @Yokhannan I have added some more info.

Comment: Just real quick... have you tested to see if shell_exec is actually turned on and working properly?   shell_exec("ls -l");

Comment: @Yokhannan Yes this code worked `shell_exec('cd. > "{MYPATH}/test.txt"');`

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. The wamp service that starts httpd does not have the correct permissions. I changed the server to login under my user account and it worked. However, how would you fix this by fixing the permissions on the default account wampapache logs into? By default it logs into "Local System account" and I checked the allow server to interact with desktop. I also added permissions on soffice.exe to allow the SYSTEM account full access but still to no avail. Any ideas on that one? Just to recap I got it working after changing the service login to my own account but I am curious on how to solve it by just fixing the permissions on the default local system account. Thanks!